# React final-form field change while remounting the field seems to not work

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I have a form in which I'm listening to changes in a field. Based on this field value, I'm setting the values for another field with `form.change('name', 'value')` function.

The thing is, that the form is quite dynamic, so the field that I need to change the value of is remounted in a different place of the components tree while being changed. I think that because of that, the change is actually not propagated to the field in final-form. Could someone give me some clue about why is that?

Here is the minimal reproduction of the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-final-form-fields-component-forked-47izwj?file=/index.js